# Markdown Code Blocks with IPython Style

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, markdown, jupyter-notebook

To render a Python block of code in markdown I use three back ticks `{python}` three back ticks:

````
```
{python}
x = 4
```
````

How can I get an IPython block of code:

```
In [1]: x = 4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: copy it from an ipython session

Comment: What's your question?  You want the `ln[1]` to show (vs hide), or you wanna know how to copy/paste code ?

Comment: I want the In[1] to show.